# Can only ping external IPs

Tags: networking, 18.04

I have a headless computer running Ubuntu 18.04. It has until recently been happily operating as a Pi-hole on my wifi (Nest Mesh).

After attempting to install some new bits and bobs on it (Home Assistant, etc.), I found out it does not have internet access. Strangely enough, I can ping my own router, but I cannot ping anything else on the network.

After a bit more fiddling around, I've removed Pi-hole and reverted as much of everything as I could to default. I can now ping 8.8.8.8, but cannot ping internal, and seem to struggle with some other sites.

[image: see here]

Comment: There is no information at all. You installed something, then removed something and it looks like DNS doesn't work. We can't guess what is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not too sure how better to explain it. Things are crook, I guess! I can ping some things, and not other things, and I can install new packages, but can't connect to ubuntu.com, it's all a bit whacky, and I'm not too sure where to start.

Comment: Obvs, I've been duckduckgo'ing this issue, but I haven't found anything too useful, so super keen to hear if anyone has ideas.

Comment: You need to look into your network settings.

Comment: Before you removed Pi-hole, the system used that to resolve names. Now that you have removed Pi-hole, you need to tell the system to look at another name server, very probably your router. You probably have NetworkManager on your system: please restart that: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Comment: It's either the bits and bobs or the fiddling or something else. (SCNR)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this in the future, the answer was simple: Pi-hole does not support Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, so when I finally established some internet access and attempted to update Pi-hole, it updated FTL, which broke a lot of configs.
So, updating to 22.04 LTS and reinstalling Pi-hole has fixed everything. Just need to change some power settings to stop the nuc from going to sleep constantly.